# Почему в C++20 убрали оператор != у std::bitset?

Tags: c++, c++20

Почему в `C++20` убрали оператор `!=` у `std::bitset`?

Comment: Тут дело в том, что `a != b` теперь при необходимости трансформируется в `!(a == b)`, это протолкнули вместе с оператором `<=>`. Сам еще не разобрался до конца, как именно все это работает.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что начиная с версии стандарта C++20 в нем (явном определении) просто больше нет необходимости. Разумеется, это не значит, что его нельзя использовать.

Теперь достаточно определить `operator==` и выражение, в котором используется `operator!=` будет преобразовано в `!operator==(...)`.

---

Приведу пример:

```
// -std=c++2a

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Annotation
{
public:
    Annotation() = default;
    explicit Annotation(std::string data) : m_data(std::move(data)) {}

public:
    friend auto operator==(const Annotation& lhs, const Annotation& rhs) -> bool
    {
        return lhs.m_data == rhs.m_data;
    }

protected:
    std::string m_data {};
};

auto main() -> int
{
    Annotation a1 { "abc" };
    Annotation a2 { "xyz" };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a1 != a2) << std::endl;
}
```

Как видите, явное определение для `operator!=` в данном примере отсутствует, тем не менее этот код является корректным. Попытка скомпилировать этот код с `-std=c++17` (`/std:c++17`) приведет к ошибке.

[Wandbox Live Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RfNZLo5uKhncow2T)

---

Рассмотрим сравение из примера выше: `a1 != a2`. На этапе компиляции выполняется поиск имен, и здесь возможно несколько вариантов развития событий:

1. Вы явно определили `operator!=`, name lookup разрешен в пользу этого оператора, он и будет вызван.
2. Явное определение `operator!=` отсутствует, при этом оператор `operator==` определен, выражение `a1 != a2` будет преобразовано к виду `!operator==(a1, a2)`.

Второй пункт требует уточнения, давайте посмотрим еще один пример:

```
class ExtendedAnnotation : public Annotation
{
public:
    ExtendedAnnotation() = default;

public:
    friend auto operator==(const ExtendedAnnotation& lhs, const Annotation& rhs) -> bool
    {
        return lhs.m_data.starts_with(rhs.data());
    }
};
```

Непосредственно сравнение:

```
auto main() -> int
{
    Annotation         a1;
    ExtendedAnnotation a2;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a1 != a2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a2 != a1) << std::endl;
}
```

Как Вы можете заметить, я определил только `operator==(const ExtendedAnnotation&, const Annotation&)`, однако работают оба варианта:

- `ExtendedAnnotation != Annotation`
- `Annotation != ExtendedAnnotation`

Т.е., при name lookup так же проверяются кандидаты с обратным порядком аргументов.

---

Более детальное описание Вы можете найти в [over.match.oper](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match#oper).

> For the != operator ([expr.eq]), the rewritten candidates include all non-rewritten candidates for the expression x == y.

> If a rewritten operator== candidate is selected by overload resolution for and
> operator @, its return type shall be cv bool, and x @ y is interpreted as:
>
> - (9.1) if @ is != and the selected candidate is a synthesized candidate with
>   reversed order of parameters, !(y == x),
> - (9.2) otherwise, if @ is !=, !(x == y),
> - (9.3) otherwise (when @ is ==), y == x, 
>   in each case using the selected rewritten operator== candidate.

Comment: На счет (1), думаю все-таки выражение преобразуется, а не определение для `operator!=` генерируется. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KvVdPM

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, согласен. Просто когда писал думал и про остальные операторы. Сейчас поправлю, спасибо.

Comment: Так а почему у `std::bitset` убрали, а у `std::stack`, например, [нет](http://eel.is/c++draft/stack.syn)?

Comment: @вася, не уверен, что могу ответить на данный вопрос. Если (у)знаете ответ - напишите, буду благодарен.

Comment: @isnullxbh пока что нарыл только предположение из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177760) *All containers have had their operator!= removed, as far as I can tell (check e.g. the vector synopsis). The only exceptions are the container adaptors std::queue and std::stack: my guess is that it is to preserve backwards compatibility when used with third-party containers, in case the equality operators are not symmetric.*

Comment: @вася, интересно, спасибо. Если тоже что-то раскопаю - напишу сюда.

Comment: @вася, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1189r0.html#adding-to-stdoptional

Answer (score 0):

В `C++20` устаревшими стали все операторы сравнения кроме `==` и `<=>`, потому что последний включает их в себя. Т.е. код по-прежнему будет работать, но не будет вызываться отдельный оператор `!=` для этого.

Подробности в этом вопросе https://stackoverflow.com/q/49812708.

Comment: Они не стали устаревшими. Операторы сравнения разделены на две категории - primary и secondary. К primary операторам относятся equality operator и spacehsip operator, к secondary - все остальные. Наличие определений для операторов из primary категории позволяет  использовать остальные операторы не вводя их явных определений.